# Typescript object literal narrowing

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I've been googling for close to two hours so now I turn to Stack Overflow for help. I am writing a function which accepts an object parameter. I can't figure out how to force TS to narrow to the type when an object literal is passed. My simple working example looks like the code below but it feels unnecessarily cumbersom:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

const getRandomValue = <T, S=Record<string, T>>(obj:S):T => {
    const values = Object.values(obj);
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length);

    return values[randomIndex];
}

const obj = {
    a: "hi",
    b: "hello",
} as const;

//this works as expected but it's cumbersome to define the literal separately and have to say "as const" to avoid the type becoming { string: string }
const value = getRandomValue<ValueOf<typeof obj>>(obj);

//prove that it works
type ValueType = typeof value;
const x:ValueType = "hello"; //allowed
const y:ValueType = "bonjour"; //shows a type error

//I was hoping I could define the function in a way where I could call it like this and still
//get the same strict typing as above: getRandomValue({ a: "hi", b: "hello" });
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#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)

Edit: removed the non-working version of code.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mbApEN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. Playground link added!

Comment: So, `ValueOf<typeof obj>`, where `obj` is of type `Record<string, string>`, is a roundabout and cumbersome way of writing `string`.  If you want to see something more specific you need to make `getRandomValue()` generic.  But is this really a [mre]?  You seem to be returning a *key* and not a *value*, and if I call `getRandomValue({x: "y"})` you are claiming that `"y"` will come out but only `"x"` can.  Could you fix this?

Comment: @jcalz sorry, I'm making a contrived example so I messed up explaining. You are correct, ValueOf<Record<string, string>> just boils down to string. That's really where I'm stuck. I could say extends Record<string, string> but that's no better. I updated the playground with my working version that doesnt feel elegant.

Comment: But do you understand that your implementation is never looking at the property values of the object passed in? It returns one of the keys.  If that’s not the intent, then fix it.  If it is the intent, then you want to return a `keyof` and not a `ValueOf`.

Comment: @jcalz please look again. Fixed the code in both the playground and the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens with your `ValueOf<T>` when you use `T = Record<string, string>` is that TS (correctly) determines that `Record<string, string>[string] = string`.

When you use `getRandomValue<T>(obj: T): ValueOf<T>` with an object literal, say with `{ foo: "bar" }`, `T` isn't `Record<string, string>` but a `Record<"foo", "bar">`.

Thus you'll need to use generics for the *record's* key and value types:

```js
const getRandomValueFromObj = <Key, Value>(obj: Record<Key, Value>): Value => {}
```

This isn't enough, however, for a few different reasons. First, TS will still determine `Key = string` and `Value = string` for e.g. `{ foo: "bar" }`, but you want string *constants*. You could write `{ foo: "bar" as const }` to promise TS that `"bar"` is constant, but it's easier to use a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) in the function definition:

```js
const getRandomValueFromObj =
    <Key, Value extends string>(obj: Record<Key, Value>): Value => {}
```

Now typescript will determine `Value = "bar"` for `{ foo: "bar" }`.

Next up, you'll have trouble with `Key` and `Object.keys`, whose signature is `.keys(o: {}): string[]`. That is, even though `o` is `Record<Key, Value>`, `Object.keys` will always return `string[]`, and [that's intentional](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208). You'll have to use a type assertion:

```js
const getRandomValueFromObj =
    <Key, Value extends string>(obj: Record<Key, Value>): Value => {
        const keys = Object.keys(obj) as Key[];
    }
```

But TS still isn't happy, since `Key` and `string` might not overlap. After all, `Key` could be anything! You'll have to constrain `Key`, too:

```js
const getRandomValueFromObj =
    <K extends string, V extends string>(obj: Record<K, V>): V => {
        const keys = Object.keys(obj) as Key[];
    }
```

Here's a working playground [link](https://tsplay.dev/wX7d1W).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Emma. I made an edit to my question to make it more clear. I understand why my original example doesnt work but I was hoping someone would have a more elegant solution than what I have written above.

Comment: @smallnoyd I'm having trouble understanding how the linked playground/last example in my answer differs from the solution you're seeking: you're able to call my solution with an object literal and get type safety without having to use `const` etc

Comment: Youre a genius. I was in the wrong playground ‍♂️

Comment: I'm confused at how TS narrows the type so much simply by putting `<K extends string, V extends string>`. Does their mere presence force the compiler to infer keys/values from the object being passed?

Comment: @smallnoyd That probably warrants its own question. Both because it's not directly related to this one anymore and because I couldn't find a canonical answer for you